# Macro to delete row in 2007 not working same working in 2003

Tags: excel, ms-office, office-2007, vba

This code is calling only one time when I open my excel sheet. The copy of data from one sheet to another sheet working just above the deletion code shown below. if I run the macro again then it is works as expected.
In 2003 both copying and deletion working when I open the sheet.

This is the code that is giving me problems:

```
Rows(ExceptionList & ":" & ExceptionList).Select 
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
```

Comment: Is this a Microsoft Excel question? Please add a tag for the correct language or environment.

Comment: This question is for [superuser](http://superuser.com). Also, "not working same" doesn't give any detail that could be used to help you. You need to be more specific. However, the solution is simple - record the macro again, and look at the source.

Comment: Hi, the code is calling only one time when i open the excel sheet. the copy of data from one sheet to another sheet working just above the deletion. if i run the macro again then it is deleting.

Comment: in 2003 both copying and deletion working when i open the sheet.

Comment: i have added the deletion in Workbook_Open() it is not working when i open in 2007 but was working in 2003.

Answer (score 0):

Is `ExceptionList` a String type?

I would avoid this whole string concatenation business and just say `Rows(rowNumberToDelete).Delete Shift:=xlUp`

Also, the whole `.Select`-`Selection.` vernacular is unnecessary and inefficient. That's how Excel machine-generates macros, but a thinking human shouldn't write like this.